# Как округлить число до заданного знака после запятой в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть калькулятор которое считает массу и длину продукта.
Как округлить результат `1532.26262626` как `1532,26`
и `0,39515151` как `0,395` тоесть в одном после дроби будет 2 числа в другом 3

```
 var result = Math.round(result);
```

этот код округляет без дробных чисел сразу целое число

Comment: А по какому принципу 0,2626 должно округляться до 0,27, а 0,39515 - до 0,395? Почему не 0,396?

Comment: @Yaant исправил) не обратил внимание

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const a = 1532.26262626;
const b = 0.39515151;

console.log(a.toFixed(2));
console.log(b.toFixed(3));
```

без 00

```js
function num(e) {
  return (e % 1) === 0 ? e.toFixed(0) : e.toFixed(2);
}

console.log(num(12.1542));
console.log(num(15));
```

Comment: решено, теперь другая проблема, когда в результате выходит целое число, например: 317 то ваш код добавляет два нуля после цифры 317,00 как сделать так чтобы если результат целое то убирать дробь